# Не могу понять в чём ошибка:InputMismatchException

Tags: java, netbeans

мой код Java:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
class DoPayroll 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
   { 
        Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("d:\\EmployeeInfо.txt")); 
        for (int empNum = 1; empNum <= 3; empNum++) 
        { 
            payOneEmployee(diskScanner); 
        } 
    } 
    static void payOneEmployee(Scanner aScanner)    
    { 
       Employee anEmployee = new Employee(); 
       anEmployee.setName(aScanner.nextLine()); 
       anEmployee.setJobTitle(aScanner.nextLine()); 
       anEmployee.cutCheck(aScanner.nextDouble()); 
       aScanner.nextLine(); 
    } 
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DoPayroll.class.getName());
}
public class Employee 
{
    private String name; 
    private String jobTitle; 
    public void setName(String nameln) 
    { 
    name = nameln; 
    } 
    public String getName()  
    { 
      return name; 
    } 
    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitleln) 
    { 
       jobTitle = jobTitleln; 
    } 
    public String getJobTitle() 
    { 
        return jobTitle; 
    } 
    public void cutCheck(double amountPaid) 
    { 
        out.printf("Выплатить служащему %s ", name); 
        out.printf("(%s) ***$", jobTitle); 
        out.printf("%,.2f\n", amountPaid); 
    } 
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Employee.class.getName());
}
```

Также имеется файл EnployeeInfo.txt

```
Барри 
Курьер 
5000,00 
1 Джейн 
Программист 
1 7000,00 
1 Кэтти 
1 Кассир 
5 10000,00
```

Файл Java нашёл,а выдаёт ошибку:InputMismatchException.
Подскажите пожалуйста,как исправить

Answer (score 0):

> public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Все просто, дело в том, что `Scanner.nextDouble();` предполагает, что введенные числа с плавающей точкой будут отделять дробную часть через точку (**.**), а не запятую (**,**), как у вас. Исправьте этот момент в входном файле и все заработает.

Вообще, это достаточно страшный и медленный способ получения информации. Намного проще, быстрее, логичнее и правильнее было бы использовать в этих целях не `Scanner` с файлом, а [`JDBC`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) с базой данных ;) Если Вам нужна [встроенная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94) БД (а судя по тому, как Вы берете данные, то именно она), то посмотрите в сторону [SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/) или других встроенных [СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Это избавит Вас от проблемы медленного парсинга текста, чреватого потенциальными ошибками.

Answer (score 0):

Формат вещественного числа зависит от текущей локали. В одних языках дробная часть отделяется точкой, в других пробелом. Чтобы не зависеть от настроек операционной системы, в которой запускается программа, установите используемую локаль явно:

```
Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("EmployeeInfo.txt"));
diskScanner.useLocale(new Locale("ru"));
```

Comment: От ошибки не избавило

Comment: Странное дело, этот способ работает на всех моим системах и ещё у кучи народа. Но в ideone.com я почему-то получаю ошибку.

Answer (score -2):

```
     Вам Ep1demic абсолютно правильно сказал про БД. Но все же поставленная Вами задача - чтение из текстового файла. Проблем тут несколько... Первая и главная в том, что вы вообще не можете предвидеть, что именно будет лежать в этом файле, отсюда можно получать неограниченное кол-во исключений. Посему предлагаю Вам немного переписать код, исключив из него тип double. Это необходимо сделать по многим причинам. Одна из них указана выше - это вечный источник исключений при парсинге. Вторая, не менее важная, заключается в том, что деньги никогда не стоит хранить в значения типа doublе. Для этих целей использовать стоит только целочисленные типы - long либо на худой конец int. Естественно, сумма указывается в копейках , центах и т.д. Разница в том, что double хранит приблизительные значения, при большом количестве вычислений эти погрешности могут давать очень нежелательные результаты.
                В данном случае я для примера заменил данное значение на стринг, дабы исключить ошибки парсинга, и заменил сканер на стримы, в данном случае, на мой взгляд, с ними проще, дальше думайте сами.

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        class DoPayroll {

            public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

                List<String> textList = loadTxtFile("d:\\EmployeeInfо.txt", "WINDOWS-1251");// or UTF-8 or else
                for (int i = 2; i < textList.size(); i+=3) {
Employee anEmployee = new Employee();
                    anEmployee.setName(textList.get(i-2).trim());
                    anEmployee.setJobTitle(textList.get(i-1).trim());
                    anEmployee.setAmountPaid(textList.get(i).trim());
                    System.out.println(anEmployee);
                }
            }

            public static List <String> loadTxtFile(String fileName, String charset) {
                List <String>list = new ArrayList <>();
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), charset))) {
                    String strLine;
                    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) list.add(strLine);
                } catch (IOException e) {}
                return list;
            }

        }

        public class Employee {

            private String name;
            private String jobTitle;
            private String amountPaid;

            public Employee() {
            }

            public Employee(String name, String jobTitle, String amountPaid) {
                this.name = name;
                this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
                this.amountPaid = amountPaid;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getJobTitle() {
                return jobTitle;
            }

            public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
                this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
            }

            public String getAmountPaid() {
                return amountPaid;
            }

            public void setAmountPaid(String amountPaid) {
                this.amountPaid = amountPaid;
            }

            //todo
            public int parseaAmountPaid() {
                return Integer.valueOf(amountPaid);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Выплатить служащему " + name + " (" + jobTitle + ") ***$" + amountPaid;
            }

        }
```